# Laravel Undefined variable: books in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The problem is undefined variable in view.
My controller:

```
use App\Book;
class bookController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
  $books = Book::all();

  return view('frontend.index')->with('books', $books);
}
}
```

I get undefined variable `books`;
I was searching here and on the web and tried many things and I still get that error.

Not sure why. Can someone help me?

Thank you

EDIT:

View:

```
@foreach ($books as $key => $book)

  <tr>

      <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>

      <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>

      <td>{{ $book->description }}</td>

  </tr>

  @endforeach
```

Comment: Post the code of view where you are trying to access the books?

Comment: Make sure you're executing `index()` method and not another one. You can do that with Laravel Debugbar.

Comment: Thank you that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

First of all your class name must start with capital letter...

Try this:

```
return view('frontend.index', ['books' => $books]);
```

instead of

```
  return view('frontend.index')->with('books', $books);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return view('frontend.index')->with(compact($books));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use App\Book;
class bookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $books = Book::all();
      $data['books'] = $books; //You may put other values too in $data array
      return view('frontend.index', $data);
    }
}
```